# How to evade negative (-1) result jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a post slideshow for wordpress on jquery. I got to say I'm no expert and this is my first time working with jquery or javascript.
Everything works perfect the code works just fine the post rotate each x seconds, there is two div's which move post left(previous) or right(next) on click, it works fine but on the first post (0) when you click left (previous) it shows nothing since 0 - 1 = -1 there is no -1 post and what is supossed to show is the last post (4).
I tried if { } else if { } but as I said I'm no expert and I can't find a solution by myself.
Any help is apreciated.
The code...

```
$("#switch-izquierda").click(
    function() {
    $("#lista-contenedor-rotatorio li:eq("+img_actual+")").fadeOut(1600);
    img_actual = (img_actual -1) % cuenta;
    $("#lista-contenedor-rotatorio li:eq("+img_actual+")").fadeIn(2000);
    });
```

The problem is here...

```
    img_actual = (img_actual -1) % cuenta;
```

When in first post (0) result is -1 what I need is to show last post(4)

If you got a solution I really appreciate it.

Comment: @waxwing
Thanks a lot for your help.
It's working great now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the remainder operator, but the modulo operator. I don't know if it exists in JS.

The easiest way may be to just to avoid the negative case by adding the length:

```
img_actual = (img_actual + cuenta - 1) % cuenta;
```